# PDO doesn't seem to create MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a database using the following code:

```
// Set up DB connection and creates the DB
try {

    $connection = new \PDO(
            'mysql:host='.Settings\Database::$host.';',
            Settings\Database::$username,
            Settings\Database::$password);

    $connection->exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".Settings\Database::$databaseName." CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATION utf8_unicode_ci;");
} catch (\PDOException $exception) {

    die("Could not connect to database: ".$exception->getMessage());
}
```

<strike>The problem is that no database is being created and I receive no error except for the fact that when I try create a table with PDO i receive this error:</strike>

**READ EDIT 2**

```
Could not connect to database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'dbname'
```

**Edit:**

I have no problem manually creating the DB with *phpMyAdmin* and similars.

**Edit 2:**

Mistakenly I thought that the error was given by the `CREATE TABLE...` statement. Instead the error is returned by the `die()` function in the exception handling.

Comment: You aren't going try to create your database every time you connect, are you?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Nope, that is just inside a `setupDB.php` script.

Comment: make sure the user has privileges to create database

Comment: then get rid of this pointless try/catch stuff and tell us at least in which row the error occurred

Comment: @Igupta I'm using the MySQL root user for that...

Comment: @YourCommonSense I get the error when i try to execute a `CREATE TABLE...` query with PDO because there's no DB...

Comment: So does it create the database?

Comment: @Igupta No it doesn't...

Comment: I suggest you to check the settings or at least the way you include them

Comment: that's why I told you to get rid of pointless try catch

Comment: Have you tried: $db->exec($query) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));

Comment: @YourCommonSense I remove the `try ... catch` stuff and put a `die()` after the `$connection->exec()` and still no DB is being created.

Comment: die is even more pointless than try. Why not just *let this code alone?*

Comment: @YourCommonSense Because I want to know exactly where the error is occurring and with the `die()` i'm totally sure that the error isn't happening after it, so thanks to it I discovered that the error was in the `exec()` statement, even though I didn't know what was it. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: You will know it only if get rid of all the pointless operators. this is the point

Comment: I appreciate sarcasm, and it was my fault for not spotting lack of enabling exceptions code, but actually only uncaught excepton will provide you with exact line number from a stack trace, while neither catch nor die with silly getMessage() will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `exec()` isn't throwing exceptions. You have to enable that for each PDO connection with an attribute like this:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

If you were getting the error message from `exec()`, you would have seen this:

> Could not connect to database: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLLATION utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1

The syntax for `CREATE DATABASE` uses the keyword `COLLATE`, not `COLLATION`.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html

Comment: Thank you for your precious answer, i really appreciate the effort in explaining it :)

Comment: I'm still not sure how the statement was working in phpMyAdmin as you said. It should be a syntax error no matter where you run it.

Comment: Oh sorry, by **manually** i meant using the phpMyAdmin GUI :S

Comment: Oh right, that's naturally going to use the correct syntax. :)